# Can't verify pydev 2.7.3 installed into Eclilpse Juno Service Release 2 (4.2)

Tags: pydev

I've just installed Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 on my Mac (10.7.5 up-to-date). The Eclipse install went fine.  It included the C/C++ IDE (1.5.2...).

Then I wanted to install PyDev and so followed the instructions at http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html to install it from within Eclipse.  After installation, there was no indication that anything was installed, either looking at Eclipse preferences or views.  However, looking at the directory structure within

```
/Applications/eclipse/features
/Applications/eclipse/plugins
```

it was obvious that quite a bit of stuff got downloaded.

I cleaned up all the recent stuff (since it didn't work) and grabbed the 2.7.3 zip file from sourceforge, as that is the second method suggested (and I found some forums with people saying that they found this method to work).  I unzipped the file into /Applications/eclipse/dropins and ended up with a file structure:

```
> Applications/eclipse
 > dropins
  > PyDev 2.7.3
   > features
    > org.python.pydev.feature .. folder
   > plugins
    > a whole bunch of com.python.pydev folders
```

But upon starting up Eclipse, there is again no indication that any Python features were picked up.

Does anybody have any suggestion?

Thanks.
Doug

Comment: What I ended up doing was removing Eclipse, then going out to Oracle at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and installing the Java 1.7.0_21 jdk and jre.  Then I re-installed Exclipse for C/C++, then downloaded and unzipped the PyDev file (from SourceForge) into the eclipse/plugins folder, and now I see that I have PyDev preferences in eclipse->preferences.

Comment: I had the same problem... installed java 7 and updated java alternative to java 7, restarted C/C++ eclipse and PyDev works!